# call multiple http and return multiple observables

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

I am trying to call multiple http and combine multiple observables to one but always emit only the last one.
I have input field with formcontrol ctl and when input a keyword, search for customer, item and task.

```
    ctl: FormControl = new FormControl();

    this.list$ = this.ctl.valueChanges
      .pipe(
        debounceTime(100),
        startWith(null),
        mergeMap((res: any) => {
          if (res) {
            this.keyword = res;
            return forkJoin([this.dataService.searchCustomer(res),
                             this.dataService.searchItem(res),
                             this.dataService.searchTask(res)]);
          } else {
            return of([]);
          }    
        })
      );
```

And I tried

```
<input  type="text" placeholder="Enter title" aria-label="Number" matInput [formControl]="ctl"
             [matAutocomplete]="auto" >
      <mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete">
          <ng-container *ngFor="let list of list$ | async ; let i = index">
            <mat-option *ngFor="let option of list | async" >
              {{option.id}}
            </mat-option>
          </ng-container>
      </mat-autocomplete>
```

But I get error You provided 'undefined' where a stream was expected. You can provide an Observable, Promise, ReadableStream, Array, AsyncIterable, or Iterable.

How can I return multiple observables and subscribe to display?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. After `forkJoin`, with `map` operator to combine the arrays from each observable into single array.

```
import {
  debounceTime,
  forkJoin,
  map,
  Observable,
  of,
  startWith,
  mergeMap,
} from 'rxjs';

this.list$ = this.ctl.valueChanges.pipe(
  debounceTime(100),
  startWith(null),
  mergeMap((res: any) => {
    if (res) {
      this.keyword = res;
      return forkJoin([
        this.dataService.searchCustomer(res),
        this.dataService.searchItem(res),
        this.dataService.searchTask(res),
      ]).pipe(map(([a, ...b]) => a.concat(...b)));
    } else {
      return of([]);
    }
  })
);
```

3. Modify the view part to render each `option` object in the `list$` observable.

```
<mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete">
  <ng-container *ngFor="let option of list$ | async ; let i = index">
    <mat-option>
      {{option.id}}
    </mat-option>
  </ng-container>
</mat-autocomplete>
```

[Demo @ StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pys4bh?file=src/main.ts)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Now I have another problem. search... method call http.get and immediately the request gets cancelled. if I pass only one request to forkJoin, it is fine though.